# R data.table: Generate random numbers

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` and I am trying to generate binomial random numbers (using `rbinom`) using the values of one of the columns as the parameter to the distribution. Assume that `index` is a unique row identifier, and that the parameter is in the `responseProb` column. Then

```
dt[, response := rbinom(1, 1, responseProb), by = index]
```

`rbinom`'s signature is `rbinom(n, size, prob)`, but since it is not vectorized over the `prob` argument, it can only take a scalar as input, so I can't, but would be able to write:

```
dt[, response := rbinom(1, 1, responseProb)]
```

To give a simple example of what I mean, `rbinom(1, 1, seq(0.1, 0.9, .1))`, yields

```
> rbinom(1, 1, seq(0.1, 0.9, .1))
[1] 1
```

I think that the solution to this is to use

```
dt[, response := rbinom(probResponse, 1, responseProb)]
```

but want to double check that this would lead to the same answer as the first line of code.

Comment: rbinom is vectorized on the prob argument.  But it will only use/generate as many observations as specified in n.  So you'll want to make sure your n is at least as large as probs is long.

Comment: If you gave a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that would help ...

Answer (score 3):

So `rbinom` is vectorized and you can use `.N` as the first argument.

```
dt[, response := rbinom(.N, 1, responseProb)]
```

To check that this gives the same result as the indexing solution, just set a seed and repeat.

```
# create reproducible example
N <- 100
dt <- data.table(responseProb = runif(N), 
                 index = 1:N)
# set seed
set.seed(1)
# your original version
dt[, response := rbinom(1, 1, responseProb), by = index]
# set seed again
set.seed(1)
# version with .N
dt[, response2 := rbinom(.N, 1, responseProb)]
# check for equality
dt[, all(response == response2)]
## [1] TRUE
```